# Internet access via browser

Tags: proxy

Is it possible to use browser's internet connection for other application?

I'm in environment where browser is the only application that may access internet connection. Meanwhile, I need to run maven projects which needs internet access to download the required JARs.

I was thinking about creating Proxy Server in Chrome extensions or other browser. But, I hope I can find another easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Recently I created a http_proxy server in Java which start 3 socket servers:

- **Http server** to receive user request, and
- **WebSocket server** to allow Chromium extension to create connection to the http_proxy server.
- **Http Server** to receive response body from Chromium.

So, there will be 3 socket connections:

- To receive http user request and send back the content, and
- To send the URL requested to Chromium browser
- When response received by browser (via Xhr), it will do HTTP POST to http_proxy server to send the content.

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) WebDriver is what you need. You could try to  redirect the download to browser or try to programmatically simulate browser.